# ReactNative : Function called twice automatically inside FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, frontend

I have been in trouble seeking a solution to the silly problem. There is something missing from my code which I am unable to understand for now. Looking forward to your answers and information regarding the below code:

Constructor:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.TotalQuery = this.TotalQuery.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        Query: [],
    }
    this.UserID();
}
```

Function()

```
  TotalQuery(product_id){
fetch(`http://:3000/api/v1/users/queries/${product_id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((resp => {
    this.setState({
        Query: resp
    })
})) .catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Api call error1");
    })
}
```

Calling this inside the Flatlist like below:

```
 <FlatList
     data={this.state.UserProducts}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
     renderItem= { ({item}) => (

     <View style={styles.order}>
       <View style={styles.orderHeader}>
          <View style={styles.ohInfo}>
            <Text style={styles.ohLabel}>Ref#</Text>
            <Text style={styles.ohValue}>#2019-{item.product_id}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.ohInfo, { backgroundColor: '#E7E7E7' }]}>
            <Text style={styles.ohLabel}>Amount</Text>
            <Text style={styles.ohValue}>€{item.price}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.ohInfo}>
            <Text style={styles.ohLabel}>Messages</Text>
            {this.TotalQuery(item.product_id)}
            {this.state.Query.map((i, index) => (
            <Text style={styles.ohValue}>{i.total}</Text>))}
          </View>
        </View>

     <View style={styles.profileImgContainer}>
        <View>
        <ImageBackground style={styles.profileImgContainer}>
        <Image source={{ uri: item.url }} style={[styles.profileImg]} />  
        </ImageBackground>
     </View>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.orderBottom}>
    <View style={styles.orderBottomLf}>
    <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }}
        source={require('../../assets/images/icon-pending-black.png')} />

    <Text 
     style={[styles.orderStatusText]}>
        {(item.status === 1) ? <Text style={styles.Approved}>Approved</Text> : null}
        {(item.status === 2) ? <Text style={styles.Sold}>Sold</Text> : null}
        {(item.status === 3) ? <Text style={styles.UnderReview}>Under Review</Text> : null}
        {(item.status === 4) ? <Text style={styles.Inactive}>Inactive</Text> : null}
        {(item.status === 5) ? <Text style={styles.Deleted}>Deleted</Text> : null}
   </Text>

   </View>

   <View style={styles.orderBottomRg}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.profileImgContainer1} onPress={() => this.Sold(item.product_id)}>
      {(item.status === 1) ? <Image style={[styles.profileImg1]} source={require('../../assets/images/checked.png')}/> : null}
   </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <View style={styles.orderBottomRg}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.profileImgContainer2} onPress={() => {this.Delete(item.product_id)}}>
       {(item.status === 1 || item.status === 3 || item.status === 4) ? <Image style={[styles.profileImg2]} source={require('../../assets/images/delete.png')}/> : null }
   </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
      </View>
    </View>
   )} 
  />
```

Above is the flatlist rendering, everything is rendering from it only. Please check.

Comment: Please post the entire Flatlist so we can help you figure out what you did wrong, what you have provided is not enough

Comment: @TravisJames Updated, please check

Comment: Okay Iooked at your update and I still don't see any function being called.  What function is called twice and where are you calling it from?

Comment: @TravisJames - {this.TotalQuery(item.product_id)} this the function which I am calling, you can find it under Style=ohInfo. And this is been called twice.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

The problem is that you are calling a function within the Flatlist `renderItem` method.

The way Flatlist works is you give it a data set and then it will call `renderItem` for each entry in that data set.

And then, any time your component re renders or the child item re renders the Flatlist will do this again.

Plus, it looks like you want to call `this.TotalQuery(item.product_id)` for each item in your data set but you are saving the return value to a single state value, so each call with overwrite the previous.

I would recommend moving your `renderItem` code into its own `Component`, and then each `Component` instance can have it's own state object where you can save the return value from your function call.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will surely try and implement this.